# Convertir valores a número

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy aprendiendo AngularJS y JavaScript, y siguiendo los ejemplos del libro que estoy usando, encuentro algo que me gustaría comprender.

Tengo un controlador que efectúa una de dos operaciones matemáticas, según el botón que se presione: sumar y multiplicar.

```
var controladorApp = angular.module('controladores', []);
controladorApp.controller('controladorConMetodos', function($scope){
  $scope.valor1 = 0;
  $scope.valor2 = 0;

  $scope.sumar = function () {
    $scope.resultado = $scope.valor1 + $scope.valor2;
  };

  $scope.multiplicar = function() {
    $scope.resultado = $scope.valor1 * $scope.valor2;
  }
});
```

En la página web, simplemente llamo a cada método con su propio botón y muestro el resultado una línea después. Los campos `input` son los mismos para ambos métodos.

```
<div class="" ng-controller="controladorConMetodos">
  <input type="text" ng-model='valor1'>
  <input type="text" ng-model='valor2'>
  <button type="button" name="sumar" ng-click="sumar()">Sumar</button>
  <button type="button" name="multiplicar" ng-click='multiplicar()'>Multiplicar</button>
  <hr>
  <p>{{ resultado }}</p>
</div>
```

Este es mi problema: cuando uso el método `multiplicar()`, el resultado es correcto. Sin embargo, cuando llamo al método **`sumar()`** los valores **se concatenan y *no se suman***.

> Supongo que tengo que hacer un *cast*, pero me gustaría saber por qué (y cómo). En el libro [*Manual del Guerrero*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VPSI8RS) no mencionan esta situación, por lo que supongo que está relacionada a mi versión de AngularJS, la `1.4.9`, frente a la `1.3.2` usada en el libro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debes utiliar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
  $scope.sumar = function () {
    $scope.resultado = parseInt($scope.valor1) + parseInt($scope.valor2);
  };

  $scope.multiplicar = function() {
    $scope.resultado = parseInt($scope.valor1) * parseInt($scope.valor2);
  }
```

Ademas, podrías utilizar `<input type="number">` para prevenir que se ingresen caracteres no numéricos.

Sino deberías agregar alguna validación de tipos.

Con respecto al por que: Esto no tiene nada que ver con AngulaJS, es javascript nada mas. Pasa que el `*` no produce el efecto pues **no tiene** una función sobre `String` entonces primero realiza la conversion del tipo y luego la multiplicación. El operador `+` **si tiene** función sobre string, que es concatenar. Por ello no hay conversion.

```
>10 * '10'
<100
>10 + '10'
<"1010"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ¿por qué `multiplicar()` funciona sin `paseInt()`, hay una función u operador específico para sumar números?

Comment: @toledano lo que pasa es que el signo + es usado para concatenación, y como tomas el input del texto como "Texto" debes parsearlo para que sepa que va a sumar y no concatenarlo.

Comment: En el libro que estoy siguiendo, @WilfredoP, no hay menciones sobre este "parseo" o _casting_, por eso preguntaba si era algo relacionado con la versión utilizada; sin embargo, validar la información, como recomienda **rnrneverdies** me parece una buena práctica.

Answer (score 3):

También podrías utilizar el elemento `<input type="number" ... />`

De esta forma no es necesario realizar la conversión en el controlador porque se realiza automáticamente (bueno, de ello se encarga la directiva [`input[number]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) incorporada en **Angular**)

Además te beneficiarías del resto de ventajas de este elemento (validación, mejoras de usabilidad,...)

Comment: ¡Excelente sugerencia! De hecho, creo que esa **es la manera correcta** y yo simplemente copié mal el ejemplo del libro. También explica muchos errores míos en desarrollos reales.

Comment: Ya te lo había sugerido @rnrneverdies en su respuesta pero no se ve por un error de formato que he intentado editar sin éxito

Comment: gracias, no lo habia notado.